# File uploading on a PHP server using OkHttp, error?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

So first of all, the Android App has the permissions and libraries set, not to mention that the PHP server has the php.ini file updated to be able to upload files.

The concept is to input a filepath to a function

```
    public String postImage (String imagePath) {

    result = ""+ System.currentTimeMillis();
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("title", "result")
            .addFormDataPart("image", result + ".png",
                    RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, new File(imagePath)))
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://192.168.0.17/addImage.php")
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                result = response.body().string();
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Then the server, has this file that gets the POST of the funtion called "addImage.php"

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    $target_dir = "images/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType =  strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}?>
```

But for some reason i get this error

```
    W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F77/ORIGINAL/NONE/294934663 (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:231)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:165)
        at okio.Okio.source(Okio.kt:194)
        at okhttp3.RequestBody$Companion$toRequestBody$3.writeTo(RequestBody.kt:162)
        at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeOrCountBytes(MultipartBody.kt:156)
        at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeTo(MultipartBody.kt:92)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:59)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:37)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:82)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:84)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:71)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:184)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:136)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe82c59a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe0ab13a0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe82c59a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe0ab13a0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe82c59a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe0ab13a0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe82c59a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe0ab13a0)
Application terminated.
```

The error says that the image path given is `(No such file or directory)`, however i am easily picking it and displaying it on Glide.
Android Studio is also telling me that RequestBody.create() is deprecated too, however the OkHttp Recipe Pages show it being used.

Edit: To clarify, the error does not come from PHP, however its coming from OkHttp in Java, or the FileInputStream, however i don't understant why

Edit2: I heve realized the error being the fact that the image path given wasnt a working one for File() to recognize, however with out errors i cannot get any files accross to the server. Any help on that?

Comment: you are creating a `File` form that `imagePath`, which is not a path in fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide all deatails and what the problem was originally.

First of all everything works now.

The original issue ocurred when the image path provided was completly wrong, this was provided by the user inputting , however Glide could easily display it, so i did display it, then got the drawable convert it to bitmap and then byte[] and finally save the image by using FileOutStream to a cache created (cache is cleaned on the onStop() funstion), finally just use `this.getCachedir()` to grap the image path.

Build the Multipart.Builder, and `.addFormDataPart("fileToUpload", result + ".png",
                        RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, new File(imagePath)))`

This way The PHP server can get `"fileToUpload"` and store it, also the PHP file requires a directory to store the images, this case being the "images/", for that pre-create that directory so the PHP file recognizes it and stores it in.

For anyone that wants to use the same library and try to upload an image use the following code

For Java:

```
    public String postImage (String imagePath) {

    result = ""+ System.currentTimeMillis();
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("fileToUpload", result + ".png",
                    RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, new File(imagePath)))
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://192.168.0.17/addImage.php")
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                result = response.body().string();
            }
        }
    });
    return "http://192.168.0.17/uploads/"+result;
}
```

The PHP Server side:

```
    <?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    $target_dir = "images/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType =  strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}?>
```

Remember to set the Permissions on your Android App, and set the php.ini to allow file uploads.